# Peewee Foreign Key is not an integer

Tags: python, peewee

I try to compare to integers but the ForeignKey Value isn't an integer:

```
class Player(Model):

    id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = CharField(max_length=32)

    class Meta:
        database = db
        db_table = "player"


class Club(Model):
    id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    owner = ForeignKeyField(Player, backref='owner')
    class Meta:
       database = db
       db_table = "club"
```

Now I try to compare the current `session["id"]` with the owner from the database:

```
club_data = Club.get(Club.id == id)
if session["id"] == club_data.owner:
    do_some_things()
```

The value `club_data.owner` isn't an integer. Did I make a mistake on the Database file?

When I try `int(club_data.owner)`, I get the following error message:
`int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Player'`

```
print(club_data.owner) is 0 and session["id"] is also 0
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `if session["id"] == club_data.owner.id`, since your second error suggests that `club_data.owner` has the type `Player`, not `int`. If it's a player you can get its `id` attribute to compare.

As a note, this:

```
print(club_data.owner) is 0 and session["id"] is also 0
```

Is not going to do what you think. `print()` will return `None` which is not `0`, so the comparison (`is`), while also throwing a warning will not ever evaluate to True.

Answer (score 0):

Internally the foreign key is an integer. But Peewee automatically gets the `Player` object for you  from that foreign key, so `club_data.owner` is that object. To get the ID, you need to access its `.id` attribute.

```
if session['id'] == club_data.owner.id:
    do_some_things()
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answerers are on the right track, but traversing the foreign-key will result in an extra query --- which is unnecessary to just compare the ID:

```
club_data = Club.get(Club.id == id)
# Replace '.owner' with '.owner_id':
if session["id"] == club_data.owner_id:
    do_some_things()
```